# Scraping through product pages

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm working through a scraping function where pages of results lead to product pages.  I've added a default maximum number of results pages, and pages per set of results, to prevent a simple mistake of crawling the whole site.

Here's what I have so far.  Does the way I'm implementing the maximums with the `for` loops make sense?  Is there a more "pythonic" way? I'm coming at this from a completely learning perspective.

```
def my_crawler(url, max_pages = 1, max_items = 1):

    for page_number in range(1, max_pages + 1):
        source_code = requests.get(url + str(page_number)).text

        products = SoupStrainer(class_ = 'productTags')
        soup = BeautifulSoup(source_code, 'html.parser', parse_only=products)

        for item_number, a in enumerate(soup.find_all('a')):
            print(str(item_number) + ': ' + a['href'])

            if item_number == max_items - 1: break

my_crawler('http://www.thesite.com/productResults.aspx?&No=')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's not a lot to say about such a simple program, mainly nitpicks.

You are violating [PEP8](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) at a few places.
The code reformatted to follow PEP8 would look like this:

```
def my_crawler(url, max_pages=1, max_items=1):
    for page_number in range(1, max_pages + 1):
        source_code = requests.get(url + str(page_number)).text

        products = SoupStrainer(class_='productTags')
        soup = BeautifulSoup(source_code, 'html.parser', parse_only=products)

        for item_number, a in enumerate(soup.find_all('a')):
            print(str(item_number) + ': ' + a['href'])

            if item_number == max_items - 1:
                break
```

In particular:

- Write method parameters compactly as `max_pages=1` instead of `max_pages = 1`
- Break line after `:`

Instead of `range(1, max_pages + 1)` I would find `range(max_pages)` simpler if you only need to do `max_pages + 1` in the code. So I'd rewrite the above as:

```
for page_number in range(max_pages):
    source_code = requests.get(url + str(page_number + 1)).text
```

And as a mild case of paranoia,
I'd prefer the `if` statement for breaking out of the loop this way:

```
if item_number >= max_items - 1:
    break
```

And yes, it's fine to break out of the loop this way.
I don't think there's a better way.

When you print the item number and the link,
I think this is slightly more readable:

```
print('{}: {}'.format(item_number, a['href']))
```

Finally, don't execute code in global scope,
it's recommended to wrap code in an `if __name__ == '__name__':` guard:

```
if __name__ == '__name__':
    my_crawler('http://www.thesite.com/productResults.aspx?&No=')
```

These are mainly just nitpicks though. You're doing fine.

Comment: Awesome. Thanks @janos. This is exactly the kind of feedback I was looking for.  Is the paranoia for item_number >= max_items from experiencing a bug or just good practice?

Comment: I'm not aware if it's a known "good practice". I can't recall experiencing a bug, but then again, I've always been this way so maybe that's why it never happened to me.